# missing dates on query output

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

I'm using cf 9 on a Windows platform

I can run an SQL statement wherein my students who have been absent for 30 days will appear on this output list. Where I am having an issue is that next to each instructor I would like to show the student's last date of attendance. This somehow I was not showing up when I run my query. The query that I am using is as follows:

```
SELECT Stuid,
       TRIM(CONCAT(name.fname,' ',name.lname)) AS OVER_30_Days,
       ltfname AS instructor,
       MAX(meedate)
FROM name
LEFT JOIN meeting
    ON meeStuid = Stuid AND
       meedate BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 31 DAY AND NOW()
LEFT JOIN squadlt
    ON squadlt = ltid
WHERE meeStuid IS NULL AND
      type = 'pupil' AND
      city = 'jackson' AND
      status = 'a' AND
      Stuid <> '432' AND
      Stuid <> '5' AND
      Stuid <> '183'
ORDER BY ltfname, OVER_30_Days
```

The resulting list below displays as such with null values in the maxdate column . Is there something that I am doing wrong?

```
Stuid     OVER_30_Days      Instructor      Max(meedate)
445       Jerry Biden       Dr. Richards    Null
446       Kenny Gold        Dr. Sondra      Null
444       Timothy Crim      Dr. Kumar       Null
```

Comment: Silly question, but do you actually record any data in the `meeting` table when a student is absent? If not, you may need a different filter..

Answer (score 1):

You can replace your direct join to the `meeting` table with a join to a subquery which uses `GROUP BY` aggregation to find the last date of attendance for each student within the last 30 days.  Here is the full query, and you'll notice that all I have done is to replace the direct to `meeting`:

```
SELECT Stuid,
       TRIM(CONCAT(name.fname,' ',name.lname)) AS OVER_30_Days,
       ltfname AS instructor,
       t.meedate
FROM name
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT meeStuid, MAX(meedate) AS meedate
    FROM meeting
    WHERE meedate BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 31 DAY AND NOW()
    GROUP BY meeStuid
) t
    ON t.meeStuid = Stuid
LEFT JOIN squadlt
    ON squadlt = ltid
WHERE meeStuid IS NULL AND
      type = 'pupil' AND
      city = 'jackson' AND
      status = 'a' AND
      Stuid <> '432' AND
      Stuid <> '5' AND
      Stuid <> '183'
ORDER BY ltfname, OVER_30_Days
```

Comment: @user1824615 - Keep in mind you may need to tweak the date comparison. `NOW()` includes both date and time, so right now the comparison would look for `meedate` values between July, 22 2016 14:55:49 - August, 22 2016 14:55:49 (inclusive). Depending on what you are storing for `meedate`, and exactly how you are defining "last 30 days", it may need a little adjustment. Also, nothing to do with the question but rather than multiple `<>` comparisons, it is simpler to use `NOT IN ('432','5',183')`

Comment: @Leigh Thanks for pointing this out.  I will let the asker try it out and provide feedback.

Comment: No problem. (Clearly you already know about the distinctions ;-)  but being a common gotcha, I figured it would not hurt to mention to the asker). Like you said, we will see what happens.